# Hooking into Active Screen (Hot) Corners

Tags: macos, desktop

Anyone know if / how it is possible to launch a custom application via the  Active Screen Corners (aka Hot Corners) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to assign custom actions to screen corners without using third party applications, but one free application for that is [CornerClick](http://greg.vario.us/cornerclick/download.text).

[image]

Comment: It's open source: https://github.com/gschueler/CornerClick.git